# Mandrill / Java - Attached Files Corrupt

Tags: java, email, pdf, mailchimp, mandrill

I was trying to use the Mandrill Wrapper for Java to attached file in email. Here is my piece of code that is working on attachment files.

```
public byte[] attachmentContent(String filepath)
{
    Path path = Paths.get(filepath);
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}

    //adding attachment
    ArrayList<MandrillAttachment> attachedFiles = new ArrayList<MandrillAttachment>();
    //file 1
    String attType = "application/pdf";
    String attName = "Indian License.pdf";
    String attContent = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(attachmentContent("C:\\LL Indian License.pdf"));
    System.out.println(attContent);
    //attach
    attachedFiles.add(new MandrillAttachment(attType, attName, attContent));
    message.setAttachments(attachedFiles);
```

However, the file keeps corrupted through the sending process. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: How do you know the file is corrupted? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I was using a wokring pdf file (meaning that, I can open and read it). However, after I send it over email, with the code I wrote, I cannot open the pdf file. When I try to open, it says the file is "damaged"

Comment: yeah but how does it look like? maybe its encoded with base64 twice ... can you post a fragment?

Comment: Well, I just tried it by opening it on Adobe Reader and it says "There was an error in opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired"

Comment: open it in a text editor then, like notepad.

Answer (score 1):

(This might be too late to answer) Use the proper encoding using Base64 to avoid this issue. I used the following code to solve the issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

List<MessageContent> listofAttachments = new ArrayList<MessageContent>();
    MessageContent attachment = new MessageContent();
    attachment.setType("application/pdf");
    attachment.setName("Test.pdf");

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\PdfTesting\\Test.pdf");

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    attachment.setContent(encodedString);
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't resolve the class MessageContent. Where does it come from? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: MessageContent is a class from Mandrill Library.